# Как написать регулярное выражение, чтобы вытащить основной домен из поддомена?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, nginx

Есть 2 домена
xxx.example.com и example.com

Мне нужно из переменной `$host` в nginx вытащить основной домен (example.com), независимо от того, есть ли там поддомен. Если бы поддомен был всегда, я бы сделал как-то так

```
\.(\S*)$
```

А как сделать, если неизвестно есть ли поддомен?

Comment: `(?<domain>[^\.]+\.([A-Z]+$|co\.[A-Z]$))` оно? https://regex101.com/r/BFw2ni/1

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/Nqgjew/1 - не знаю есть ли такое в nginx, но можно попробовать

Comment: @SeniorPomidor думаю, похоже, но надо немного допилить, сейчас попробую

Answer (score 0):

`(?<domain>[^\.]+\.([A-Z]+$|co\.[A-Z]$))`

проверка [тут](https://regex101.com/r/BFw2ni/1)